# The efficiency of HAVING vs subquery and why

Tags: mysql, sql

When I study the SQL HAVING tutorial, it says: HAVING is the “clean” way to filter a query that has been aggregated, but this is also commonly done using a subquery.

Sometimes, HAVING statement is equivalent to subquery, like these:

```
select account_id, sum(total_amt_usd) as sum_amount 
from demo.orders
group by account_id
having sum(total_amt_usd) >= 250000
```

```
select *
from (
    select account_id, sum(total_amt_usd) as sum_amount 
      from demo.orders
      group by account_id
      ) as subtable
where sum_amount >= 250000
```

I want to know which one is recommended and the reason why this one is faster or more efficient than the other.

Comment: Since the `HAVING` clause is processed after the `GROUP BY` aggregation and `WHERE` criteria, you only need to use `HAVING sum_amount >= 250000`. Example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c3b1a/4 As for why `HAVING` is preferred, it is generally due to readability and predictability, such as the queried table schema changing or query caching. There is no real performance benefit in the provided use-case of either method.

Answer (score 1):

As with any performance question, you should try it on your data.  But, the two should be essentially equivalent.  If you are interested in such questions, then you should learn how to read execution plans.

Just one note about MySQL.  MySQL tends to materialize subqueries.  This *might* incur a little extra overhead by writing the `group by` results before filtering them, but you probably would not notice the difference.

Comment: by "materialize" you mean saving the subquery result to the disk storage?

Comment: @mangusta . . . Yes.  The `GROUP BY` has to process the data on disk, but I just wonder if the execution plan might be just a little different with a subquery.

Comment: Which one is faster when execute?

Comment: @mangusta Not necessarily disk storage.  That depends on the available memory. If the result set is not very big, nothing will actually be written to disk.